# How to represent Span<T> list/array

Tags: c#, c#-7.2

I'd like to interleave several Memory/Span buffers. Is it possible to do this without repeatedly accessing the Span property in the inner loop?

```
public static void Interleave(StreamWriter s, ReadOnlyMemory<float>[] data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.First().Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
        {
            s.Write(data[j].Span[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but accessing the `Span` property is the way to work with the ReadOnlyMemory buffer (which exists because it's counterpart ReadOnlySpan can only live on the stack, [as explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to represent a `Span<int>[]` or `Span<Span<int>>`, but I used a recursive unsafe function to achieve a similar result with a `int**` pointer. Unfortunately, it doesn't generalize very well.

```
|                 Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|----------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
|        InterleaveArray | 1.405 ms | 0.0125 ms | 0.0111 ms |
|   InterleaveMemorySpan | 4.232 ms | 0.0659 ms | 0.0616 ms |
| UnsafeInterleaveMemory | 1.374 ms | 0.0143 ms | 0.0134 ms |
```

Note that repeatedly accessing the Span property on Memory is 3x slower that the other two implementations. Here's the code I used:

```
public class InterleaveTests
{
    private Action<int> act = x => { };
    public static int[][] CreateBuffers(int BufferCount, int BufferSize)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, BufferCount)
            .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, BufferSize)
                .Select(j => j * BufferCount + i).ToArray()).ToArray();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(MemoryNumbers))]
    public void InterleaveMemorySpan(Memory<int>[] data)
    {
        var rows = data.First().Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
                act(data[j].Span[i]);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(MemoryNumbers))]
    public unsafe void UnsafeInterleaveMemory(Memory<int>[] data)
    {
        var dataBuffers = stackalloc int*[data.Length];
        Pin(data.AsSpan(), 0);

        void Pin(Span<Memory<int>> buffers, int bufferIndex)
        {
            if (buffers.Length == 0)
            {
                InterleaveMemory(data.First().Length, data.Length, dataBuffers);
            }
            else
            {
                fixed (int* pData = buffers[0].Span)
                {
                    dataBuffers[bufferIndex] = pData;
                    Pin(buffers.Slice(1), bufferIndex + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        void InterleaveMemory(int rows, int columns, int** dataSpans)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                    act(dataSpans[j][i]);
        }
    }


    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(ArrayNumbers))]
    public void InterleaveArray(int[][] data)
    {
        var rows = data.First().Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
                act(data[j][i]);
    }

    public IEnumerable<int[][]> ArrayNumbers()
    {
        yield return CreateBuffers(16, 32 * 1024);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Memory<int>[]> MemoryNumbers()
    {
        yield return CreateBuffers(16, 32 * 1024).Select(x => x.AsMemory()).ToArray();
    }
}
```